# What is the recommended way of detecting a mobile device in a view in Django 1.7+?

Tags: python, django

I've looked at other stackoverflow posts on this issues, but the replies either seem to be outdated or the git repos no longer exist.

What is the recommended way of detecting a mobile device in Django for versions 1.7+?

As a use case, I need this functionality to direct users to the mobile site if they are on a mobile device and to the desktop version of the site otherwise.

Comment: Have you tried minidetector?

Comment: I haven't. I found a stable git repo that I will try: https://github.com/mliu7/django-minidetector

Comment: Just tried it and have a working implementation running! Simply download the git repo above, and copy and paste the folder content into the directory where you have your django project. Then add "'minidetector.Middleware'," to MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES in settings.py

Answer (score 2):

Depending on if you want to use User-Agent or not, you can write a pretty simple middleware class to do so

```
class UserAgentMiddleware():
    def process_request(request):
        if request.META.HTTP_USER_AGENT == (MOBILE):
            do_something()
        else:
            return None
```

Then add this to your middleware

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
     ...
     'path.to.UserAgentMiddleWare',
     ...
]
```

To do this by screen-size (device screen size), you'd need to write some javascript, and then at the top of the page use an AJAX call to redirect to the mobile site.

```
 var width = (window.innerWidth > 0) ? window.innerWidth : screen.width;
 if (width < X) {
      window.location = window.location.protocol + "MOBILE_SITE_HERE" + window.location.pathname
 }
```